# MIcrosoft Wireless 3050 Mouse not working on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: wireless, mouse, 19.10, microsoft

Having a wireless [3050 microsoft mouse and keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/wireless-desktop-3050/pp3-00001) I am trying to get it working but it seems that when I plug the USB, Ubuntu doesn't detect it at all. Is that even possible to get that product work with 19.10? I never tried a microsoft product before on Ubuntu so I don't know even if that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to look in /var/log/kern.log for any error messages. Even better, I have found that tailing all logs will help resolve many issues:

```
sudo tail -fn0 /var/log/{*,*/*}
```

If you find that there are no error messages when you plug in the mini-tranceiver, it might not be an issue with the keyboard at all. Some possible causes for this issue could be:

- BIOS settings - check that USB hasn't been disabled.
- faulty tranceiver
- faulty usb port